# Serving StyleSheet and JS with Sails

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am a newbie at working with nodeJS and especially with the framework Sails.

I did my research and found that with sails you just need to put CSS-files under the the folder "assets" and call them directly with the URL, e.g. if I put the file `custom.css` in the folder "assets/foo" I should be able to access it via the URL "localhost:1337/foo/custom.css".

The problem is that my local server throws a 404 Error not being able to find the files, but strangely when I deployed the app to Heroku it works perfectly and I am able to access the css files.

Why is this not working locally?

Comment: Is your server running at port 1337? Can you reach other routes apart from the custom.css? Can you check your application-logs for any hints what is going wrong?

Comment: Did you restart your app after making changes? Some sorts of changes will take effect while the app is running, but others may require a restart (or just some time to pass if the app is running in dev mode). Try restarting your app and see if you still get 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Sails! CSS is served automatically if you put it in your `assets/styles` folder. Your JS should be in `assets/js` folder as well. This way you can access it like `localhost:1337/assets/js/myjs.js`.

In your view - if you don't want to serve it everywhere with a layout - just put your tag like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/myawesomestyle.css">` or `<script src="/js/mypowerfuljs.js"></script>`.
Remember, everything in assets will be made publicly available.
I really recommend that you read the docs [HERE](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/assets).

Comment: thank you. i understand now. but, if i put a lot of css files in styles folder ( automatic import) , it will not slow the application loading ??

Comment: Sails takes care of multiple .CSS and .JS by minifying those in production mode. But only the ones you are serving in the `pipeline.js` config file. So if I have `bootstrap.min.css`, `fa.css`, `any.css`, in the pipeline they will be turned into a single `production.css` that will be served to your views. So in the worst case scenario we have 4 files to load: `production.js`, `production.css`, `specificscriptforthisview.js` and `specificstyleforthisview.css`.